# Conditional WHERE clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample query like this

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max) = ''
print len(@var);
with tmp1 as (select 1 as col1,'2' as col2 
                union all select 1 as col1,'1' as col2)
select top 1 * from tmp1 where (len(@var)>0 AND col2 = @var)
```

What I want is if @var is not empty, I will select top 1 from tmp1 where col2 equal to @var. If empty, then select whatever is top 1 from the tmp1. But if I run the query above where @var is empty, I do not get any result.

Comment: Don't do that. You'll end up *harming* performance for no benefit. The code isn't simpler, safer or more flexible since you have to provide *something* for all parameters. [This](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) provides a detailed explanation. Use LINQ or an ORM on the *client* to generate and submit a query that only does what's needed

Comment: This harms performance because SQL Server caches execution plans the first time a query is submitted. If the parameter is null or empty, SQL Server will probably create an executino plan that *doesn't* use indexes that cover `col2`. When a value is actually submitted for `val` the server will perform a slow scan instead of a fast index seek.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your advise sir, I'll consider it when I get a hold of the client side.

Comment: Why do you want that query anyway? Most likely there are better, faster ways to do it. Using LINQ is one way. Worst case, you can add `WITH PRECOMPILE` to the query/stored procedure definition to avoid bad plans. An `IF` statement that executes different queries would be better if you only have one parameter

Comment: We're using hibernate on the client side. I don't have authority on it. I've used nvarchar to build the query before though. You think its better? I just saw the where condition and thought it uses less coding.

Comment: Less coding to do *what*? This query can end up querying every row in a 100K row table to find a match even if an index already exists. It *won't* be faster than Hibernate's queries either

Comment: Okay sir thank you btw, I was asking if its better to do an if else statement or put the select query on a nvarchar first then concat the where clause if @var is not empty then execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the query to say,

- either `@var` is empty
- OR it is equal to `col2`

  ```
  len(@var) = 0 OR col2 = @var
  ```

Here's the updated query:

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max) = ''
print len(@var);
with tmp1 as (select 1 as col1,'2' as col2 
                union all select 1 as col1,'1' as col2)
select top 1 * from tmp1 where (len(@var) = 0 OR col2 = @var)
```

Comment: Which will harm performance by using inefficient execution plans 50% of the time

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
  DECLARE @var varchar(max) = ''
    print len(@var);
    with tmp1 as (select 1 as col1,'2' as col2 
                    union all select 1 as col1,'1' as col2)
    select top 1 * from tmp1 where  isnull(@var,'')='' or col2 = @var
```